# Is javascript supported for most smartphone nowadays?

Tags: javascript, mobile, smartphone

I've always been thinking it's not supported until yesterday I login to gmail in my phone.

I can see hints in red if I forget to input password.

If javascript is not supported,how's that implemented?

Answer (score 1):

First, *yes* most smart phones support it at least somewhat, the major phone support it very well (iPhone, Droid, etc have very good support for example, some of the new BlackBerry phones with WebKit based browsers do as well...and I'm sure there are others I'm unaware of).

*If* the phone doesn't support JavaScript, normal non-AJAXy behavior happens, and when you post to the server, the page that comes back has the element styled with red/error styling.
This behavior works with or without JavaScript.